# solr lucene query date range format issue

Tags: solr, lucene, alfresco

in my availabe date in  solar is this

> {http://www.cchindia.co.in/model/cch/dtax/notification/1.0}dTaxNotificationDate
>   Tue Mar 12 00:00:00 IST 2013

and display date as  Mar 12, 2013

but when we search date range through lucene query

```
+PATH:"//app:company_home//cm:CCH_India//cm:Direct_Tax//cm:Releases//cm:Notifications//*" 
+(TYPE:"dTaxNotification:notificationDoc" NOT TYPE:"dTaxReadyReckoner:readyreckonerDoc"     NOT TYPE:"dTaxDtaa:dtaaDoc") 
+  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ @dTaxNotification\:dTaxNotificationDate:"[Feb 04, 2010 TO Dec 30, 2013]" 
AND
[Tue Mar 12 00:00:00 IST 2013 TO NOW],
or 
[* TO *]
```

and query result is 0 but when we search like this

```
+  @cch\:contentState:"Published"+ @dTaxNotification\:dTaxNotificationDate:"*Feb 04, 2010*"
```

then give all 2010 result

can any one suggest me perfect query is

> my date format is -> Tue Mar 12 00:00:00 IST 2013
>
> display format is -> Mar 12, 2013

Comment: I cannot distinguish your writings from you samples. Please edit you post and keep the [How do I format my posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in mind.

Answer (score 4):

dates in lucene queries are normally a subset of ISO8601:
e.g.

`[2013-12-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 TO 2013-12-31T23:59:59.999+00:00]`

to get all objects within dec 2013.

Furthermore you should not mix + & AND Syntax!